# Set ACF select2 option via Javascript when using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to select an option in an Advanced Custom Fields select2 drop down that is lazy loaded by Ajax. The new Javascript API is very powerful, but I can't figure out how to set an option when Ajax is in play.

This works without Ajax, but not with:

```
var select = acf.getField('field_5c6ce2e0b5780');
select.select2.selectOption(7);
```

Anyone have any ideas how to make this work with Ajax?

Answer (score 4):

After sifting through acf-input.js and also the Select2 documentation, I have found a way to do it using the `addOption` method. I'm not sure if this is a workaround, but it is working for my situation.

```
var select = acf.getField('field_5c6ce2e0b5780');
select.select2.addOption({
          id: 12345,
          text: 'New Option',
          selected: true
        });
```

This appears to be adding a new option to the list, but it doesn't override the option that is pulled from Ajax, so it works for my situation.